# AWS Amplify Billing for different applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have two web applications hosted via AWS Amplify. I wanted to know, is it possible to have separate billing for both applications.

Say the first application has Credit Card X and the second application has Credit Card Y.

Is that something that's possible in AWS? If so how? I tried looking in AWS documentation, but haven't found a solid solution.

Comment: Is it solved? I've got the same problem.